# Showing that Equality Holds for $\mathbb{P} ( X + Y + Z \leq 15) = \mathbb{P}(X+Y+Z \geq 26)$ for R.V.s $X, Y, Z$

Tags: probability-theory

I am a bit struggling to prove the following:

Let $X$ be the outcome of a standard die roll, $Y$ the outcome of an icosahedral die roll - 20 faces - and $Z$ the outcome of a dodecahedral die roll - 12 faces. If the three dice are rolled simultaneously, how can I show that$\mathbb{P} ( X + Y + Z \leq 15) = \mathbb{P}(X+Y+Z \geq 26)$?

So far, I have been trying to algebraically manipulate the probabilities, but I got stuck. This is what I have:
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P} (X+Y+Z \leq 15) &= \sum_{k=3}^{15} \mathbb{P}(X+Y+Z = k) \\
&= \sum_{k=3}^{15} \sum_{i=1}^{k} \sum_{j=1}^{k} \mathbb{P}(X=i, Y=j, Z=k-(i+j))
\end{align*}
With this expression, I am not entirely sure how to proceed to show that the inequality holds. I would appreciate any help on how to prove this!

Comment: I haven't thought this through very much from a mathematical perspective, but as someone who plays games a lot, I can't help but notice that the maximum of $X+Y+Z$ is $6+20+12=38,$ the minimum is $3,$ and there is the coincidence $15+26=3+38.$ Perhaps someone better versed in probability can use this to their advantage.

Comment: @Will R Also intuitively, it makes sense that these two probabilities have to be equal by symmetry. But I can't find a way to formally prove it

Comment: (cont.) In particular, it seems like there is some inherent symmetry in the problem. Perhaps it is as simple as "the map $(x, y, z) \mapsto (7-x, 21-y, 13-z)$ is a bijection between possible events on the left-hand side and possible events on the right-hand side, so the probabilities must be equal." Does that work? If so, I'll leave you the hard work of writing it up as an answer, and maybe I'll come back in the morning to give an upvote. :) (It is 2 am where I am as I write this.)

Answer (score 1):

Let $W:=X+Y+Z$, then as these three r.v. are independent and symmetric w.r.t. it own mean then it is enough to show that addition of independent and symmetric r.v. defines a symmetric random variable respect to it mean, that is, we want to show that
$$
\Pr[X+Y\leqslant  \mu-c]=\Pr[X+Y\geqslant\mu+c],\quad \text{ for all }c\text{ with }\mu:=\mathrm E[X+Y]
$$
whenever $\Pr[X\leqslant\mathrm E[X]-c]=\Pr[X\geqslant \mathrm E[X]+c]$ and $\Pr[Y\leqslant  \mathrm E[Y]-c]=\Pr[Y\geqslant  \mathrm E[Y]+c]$ for all $c$. WLOG we can assume that $\operatorname{E}[X]=\operatorname{E}[Y]=0$ as the r.v. $X-\operatorname{E}[X]$ and $Y-\operatorname{E}[Y]$ will be symmetric respect to zero, then
$$
\begin{align*}
\Pr [X+Y\leqslant  c]&=\int_{\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2:x+y\leqslant c\}}\mathop{}\!d F_{X,Y}(x,y)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\left(\int_{(-\infty ,c-y]}\mathop{}\!d F_X(x)\right)\mathop{}\!d F_Y(y)\\
&=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\Pr [X\leqslant c-y]\mathop{}\!d F_Y(y)\overset{*}{=}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\Pr [X\geqslant y-c]\mathop{}\!d F_Y(y)\\
&=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\left(\int_{[y-c,\infty )}\mathop{}\!d F_X(x)\right)\mathop{}\!d F_Y(y)=\int_{\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2:y-c\leqslant x \}}\mathop{}\!d F_{X,Y}(x,y)\\
&=\int_{\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2:y\leqslant x+c \}}\mathop{}\!d F_{X,Y}(x,y)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\left(\int_{(-\infty ,x+c]}\mathop{}\!d F_Y(y)\right)\mathop{}\!d F_X(x)\\
&=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\Pr [Y\leqslant x+c]\mathop{}\!d F_X(x)\overset{*}{=}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\Pr [Y\geqslant  -x-c]\mathop{}\!d F_X(x)\\
&=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\left(\int_{[-x-c,\infty )}\mathop{}\!d F_Y(y)\right)\mathop{}\!d F_X(x)=\int_{\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2:-x-c\leqslant y\}}\mathop{}\!d F_{X,Y}(x,y)\\
&=\int_{\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2:-c\leqslant x+y\}}\mathop{}\!d F_{X,Y}(x,y)=\Pr [X+Y\geqslant -c]
\end{align*}
$$
where in the steps marked with $*$ I used the symmetry of $X$ and $Y$ respect to zero, and where I used it independence in the identity $\mathop{}\!d F_{X,Y}=\mathop{}\!d F_X \mathop{}\!d F_Y$. Therefore we conclude that $W$ is symmetric respect to it mean, and $\operatorname{E}[W]=\operatorname{E}[X]+\operatorname{E}[Y]+\operatorname{E}[Z]=\frac{7}{2}+\frac{21}{2}+\frac{13}{2}=\frac{41}{2}$. By last note that $26=\frac{41}{2}+\frac{11}{2}$ and $15=\frac{41}{2}-\frac{11}{2}$.∎

Answer (score 1):

This answer is essentially a special case of that provided by Masacroso, but I feel it provides a distinct enough perspective to warrant exposition.

---

You are rolling a D6, a D20 and a D12. The outcome of your experiment is a triple $(x,y,z)$ of numbers, with $1\leq x \leq6,$ $1\leq y\leq 20,$ and $1\leq z\leq 12.$ Hence the sample space is just $\Omega=\{1,\ldots,6\}\times\{1,\ldots,20\}\times\{1,\ldots,12\}.$ The random variable you are interested in is $X+Y+Z\colon\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$ given by $(x,y,z)\mapsto x+y+z.$

You want to show that $\mathbb{P}(X+Y+Z\leq 15) = \mathbb{P}(X+Y+Z\geq26).$ By definition,
$$\mathbb{P}(X+Y+Z\leq k) = \frac{\lvert\{(x,y,z)\in\Omega:x+y+z\leq k\}\rvert}{\lvert \Omega\rvert} = \frac{\lvert\{(x,y,z)\in\Omega:x+y+z\leq k\}\rvert}{1440}.$$
Now note that if $(x,y,z)\in\Omega$ satisfies $x+y+z\leq 15,$ then $(7-x,21-y,13-z)\in\Omega$ also, and $(7-x)+(21-y)+(13-z)\geq26.$ Moreover, the map $\Omega\to\Omega$ given by $(x,y,z)\mapsto(7-x,21-y,13-z)$ is a bijection. Therefore,
$$\lvert\{(x,y,z)\in\Omega:x+y+z\leq 15\}\rvert = \lvert\{(x,y,z)\in\Omega:x+y+z\geq 26\}\rvert.$$
Hence the result.

---

To relate this argument back to your own attempt, note that what I have essentially shown is that $\mathbb{P}(X+Y+Z=k) = \mathbb{P}(X+Y+Z=7+21+13-k) = \mathbb{P}(X+Y+Z=41-k).$ Plugging this into your attempt gives the answer, and indeed, this is essentially what Masacroso does in their answer (but in more high-falutin' language).